# Error inserting image icon in java - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, icons, java-resources

I'm developing a java project for a university exam. The project involves the creation of an application with the JDBC methodology. The project is almost finished, I was dedicating myself to the aesthetic part and here the problems begin :( .
I'm trying to put an icon to the application with the following instructions:

```
public MainFrame() {
        try {
            setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/icon.png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Icon Image could not be loaded");
        }
```

The console gives me this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1358)
    at Boundary.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:52)
    at Boundary.MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:38)
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Where is the image located

Comment: That's a good and proper url path - as long as the file is at it ;)

Comment: @Jens I The file is in the "resources" folder

Comment: Is the resources folder on the classpath? See: [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

Answer (score 0):

The resources folder does not exists inside the deliverable.
You have to address it as it is in the root directory

```
setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
```

Comment: That *might* be the case (e.g. it would be in Maven). It depends on what was used to do the dev